# Libgdx TiledMapRenderer with TmxMapLoader spikes

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm having an issue with the TiledMapRenderer in a scrolling game that I'm developing. I'm currently using a BatchTiledMapRenderer with a Tmx Map (I've also tried with plain TiledMapRenderer). My Camera view (I'm using a Stage) is 16x10 tiles and the map is 98x14 tiles long. The map renders fine on my computer on 900x510 resolution but when I increase it to 1280x720 resolution and mostly when I port it on my mobile, occasionally the scrolling is not so smooth; however in most of the time it is smooth. I should also mention that my tile set is made by 64x64 tiles.

I'm currently puzzled at what I am doing wrong and I would appreciate any suggestion you can provide. Below are parts of the code.

The Camera Position is updated inside my `mainCharacter` class which extends `Actor` class and is updated each frame when the game is Running.

Inside my `Actor` `act` method:

```
world.getCamera().position.set(this.getX(), (MyFirstGame.CAMERA_HEIGHT+2)/2f, 0);
```

In my `Stage` class:

```
private TiledMap map;
private BatchTiledMapRenderer renderer;
```

In `Stage` Constructor:

```
Assets.manager.setLoader(TiledMap.class, new TmxMapLoader(new InternalFileHandleResolver()));
Assets.manager.load("data/maps/" + level + ".tmx", TiledMap.class);
Assets.manager.finishLoading();
map = Assets.manager.get("data/maps/" + level + ".tmx");
renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, 1f / 64f);
```

In `Stage` Render Method:

```
this.getCamera().update();
renderer.setView((OrthographicCamera) this.getCamera());
renderer.getSpriteBatch().begin();
renderer.renderTileLayer(skyLayer);
renderer.renderTileLayer(layer2);
renderer.renderTileLayer(layer3);
renderer.renderTileLayer(layer4);
renderer.renderTileLayer(layer5);
renderer.renderTileLayer(foregroundLayer);
renderer.renderTileLayer(waterLayer);
renderer.getSpriteBatch().end();

super.draw();
```

Answer (score 0):

It actually did that to me for the simple reason that the other states of the game I launched (that crashed) where still running. To fix this, I did this in my `main(String[] args)` method :

```
try {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
    config.vSyncEnabled = true;
    config.width = 1920;
    config.height = 1080;
    config.useGL20 = true;
    config.title = "AHH";
    new LwjglApplication(new GameClass(), config);
}
catch (Exception e) {
Gdx.app.exit();
System.out.println(e);
}
```

also, I recommend making sure all the other instances of your game are already close by opening the task manager.